# Missing ceph vfs module for Samba

Tags: apt, samba, ceph

I am trying to use the [samba ceph vfs module](https://www.mankier.com/8/vfs_ceph).

I installed `samba-vfs-modules` but the `ceph.so` module doesn't show up in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/vfs/`

[This mailing list post](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2014-February/179206.html) would seem to indicate the version of samba I have should include this module.

```
user@kubuntu:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l
user@kubuntu:~$ samba --version
Version 4.1.6-Ubuntu
```

Perhaps the `ceph.so` module has been broken out into a separate package?  I used http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to search for the `ceph.so` filename but didn't pick up anything in any of the releases.

Is this supposed to be installed from source or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up installing Samba from source to add direct support for the Ceph distributed file system and it worked beautifully.

Using Samba to directly access Ceph did seem to work better then resharing either kernel or fuse mount points.

I have not tried [Erik](https://askubuntu.com/users/591378/erik%22Erik%22)'s answer as the problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a samba version higher than 4.2 
Use Ubuntu Xenial.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/vfs_ceph.8.html

Regards,
Erik